# Sed get text from start until after the match ends

Tags: unix, sed

I want to get out the text from start to the match ends. 
For example:

```
Hello my name is F!Hello my name is Tom. No my name is Phil.
```

Show everything to "!" so I'm only getting out "Hello my name is F" but wat I want is "Hello my name is F!"

Comment: What should the output be if the line was `Hello my name is F!Hello my name is Tom! No my name is Phil!`?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can substitute everything you don't want with `"!"`, i.e.

```
  echo "Hello my name is F!Hello my name is Tom. No my name is Phil." \
  | sed 's/!.*$/!/'
```

**output**

```
Hello my name is F!
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\1` to keep part of a pattern that you are interested in:

```
$ echo "Hello my name is F! no no" | sed -e 's/\(\!\).*/\1/'
Hello my name is F!
```

If you want to use `![any symbol right after !]` like in our example, you will get escaped `!`:

```
$ echo -e "Hello my name is F\!Hello my name is Tom. No my name is Phil." | sed -e 's/\(\!\).*/\1/g'
Hello my name is F\!
```

To prevent this you can feed the result to yet another `sed` script:

```
~$ echo -e "Hello my name is F\!Hello my name is Tom. No my name is Phil." | sed -e 's/\(\!\).*/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\\//g'
Hello my name is F!
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is "test", this will print out each line of test up to and including the "!"

```
sed -e 's/\(.*!\).*/\1/' test
```